# Logical or groups regex

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I am trying to make a regex that will find certain cases of incorrectly entered fractions, and return the numerator and denominator as groups.

These cases involve a space between the slash and a number: such as either `1 /2` or `1/ 2`.

I use a logical-or operator in the regex, since I'd rather not have 2 separate patterns to check for:

```
r'(\d) /(\d)|(\d)/ (\d)'
```

(I'm not using `\d+` since I'm more interested in the numbers directly bordering the division sign, though `\d+` would work as well).

The problem is, when it matches one of the cases, say the second (`1/ 2`), looking at all the groups gives `(None, None, '1', '2')`, but I would like to have a regex that only returns 2 groups--in both cases, I would like the groups to be ('1', '2'). Is this possible?

**Edit:**
I would also like it to return groups ('1', '2') for the case `1 / 2`, but to not capture anything for well-formed fractions like `1/2`.

Comment: What is the required outputs for `1/2` and `1 / 2`?

Comment: Good point, updated question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`(\d)(?: /|/ | / )(\d)` should do it (and only return incorrectly entered fractions). Notice the use of no-capture groups.

Edit: updated with comments below.

Comment: What does the first non-capture group do? Just make the `|` work for the two non-captures?

Comment: I updated the question in response to Naveed's comment, but I think this is the way I'll go (but adding the case for `1 / 2`, i.e. `(\d)(?:(?: /)|(?:/ )|(?: / ))(\d)`). If you can update it, I'll accept.

Comment: At least get rid of the inner groups: `(\d)(?: /|/ | / )(\d)`.

Comment: I updated it, thanks for the tip Tim, I wasn't sure of operator order.

Answer (score 3):

What about just using `(\d)\s*/\s*(\d)`?

That way you will always have only two groups:

```
>>> import re
>>> regex = r'(\d)\s*/\s*(\d)'
>>> re.findall(regex, '1/2')
[('1', '2')]
>>> re.findall(regex, '1 /2')
[('1', '2')]
>>> re.findall(regex, '1/ 2')
[('1', '2')]
>>> re.findall(regex, '1 / 2')
[('1', '2')]
>>>
```

Comment: I like this one because of the generality. Unfortunately it's twice as slow as the other answer when doing substitutions, which wouldn't be a problem but all the regex's that I'm doing are starting to add up in my application...